# Edit a cell value once a row is found via search string

Tags: vba, excel

Hi i have a spreadsheet and some user forms to look at controlling stocks. im having a problem where i need to edit one cell value after a the row is found via some search code.

The spreadsheet:

6 Columns: Barcode number, Batch Number, Item Code, Description, Qty, Best Before

Unlimited Rows

The original code i have to search and delete a row (Works Fine):

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range

On Error GoTo Err

'~~> Set the sheet where you want to search the IMEI
Set ws = Sheets("Stock Sheet")

With ws
    '~~> Get the value which you want to search
    strSearch = TextBox1.Value

    '~~> Column A is Column 1 so Column B is 2. This is where we are searching
    '~~> xlWhole is used in the code below so that we find a complete match
    '~~> xlPart is supposed to be used when you are finding a partial match.
    Set aCell = .Columns(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    '~~> Check if we found the value
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        '~~> get the row of the cell where we found the match and delete it
        .Rows(aCell.Row).Delete
    Else '<~~ If not found
        MsgBox "Pallet Number not Found"
    End If
End With

Exit Sub
Err:
MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

But i want to change   .Rows(aCell.Row).Delete  so that instead of it deleting the complete row i want it to change the cell value in column 5 (qty) to a value based on the input into Textbox2 on the form

Not sure if i have explained it properly any help would be greatly appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follow:

```
If Not aCell Is Nothing Then        
    aCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = TextBox2.Value
Else 
    MsgBox "Pallet Number not Found"
End If
```

I just show a part to modify.